# No provider for AccordionComponent

Tags: angular

We are creating an angular2 app, and using the accordion component found in bootstrap  ng2-bootstrap accordion.

It is used in html markup like this

```
<accordion>
... blah blah html 
</accordion>
```

and even though it has been used in many other pages, in one page it throws an exception:

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./MyComponent class
MyComponent - inline template:1:0 caused by No provider for AccordionComponent!

Why is this?

Comment: The error say that you are trying to use a component that is not provided. Did you import it https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: Are you trying to inject it in the constructor? If so, maybe you should @ViewChild it instead

Comment: Please post your component code

Answer (score 8):

The answer is quite simple actually.
the markup had

```
<accordion-group>
....
</accordion-group>
```

without an accordion tag surrounding it.
That caused the error message as written above.

Sorry for that.

The component code had no mentions of accordion at all